# Vagrant doesn't provision shell script

Tags: shell, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I have a `Vagrant` file that looks like this

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION ||= "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = confDir + "/Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.require_version '>= 1.9.0'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.box_check_update = false
    if File.exist? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "/tmp/bash_aliases"
        config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
            s.inline = "awk '{ sub(\"\r$\", \"\"); print }' /tmp/bash_aliases > /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases"
        end
    end

    if File.exist? homesteadYamlPath then
        settings = YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath))
    elsif File.exist? homesteadJsonPath then
        settings = JSON.parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath))
    else
        abort "Homestead settings file not found in #{confDir}"
    end

    Homestead.configure(config, settings)

    if File.exist? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath, privileged: false, env:  {VM_VAR:ENV['HOST_VAR']}
    end

    if defined? VagrantPlugins::HostsUpdater
        config.hostsupdater.aliases = settings['sites'].map { |site| site['map'] }
    end
end
```

it's [laravel homestead](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/Vagrantfile) `Vagrantfile` but with change inside of `if File.exist? afterScriptPath then` I've just added `env`.

But the thing is when I try to run `vagrant provision`, it runs all homestead scripts, but doesn't run mine. Mine is `after.sh` (or `afterScriptPath` variable) there I've put simple shell script like

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo -s
echo 'installing some extra software'
echo $VM_VAR
touch /usr/local/extra_homestead_software_installed
```

to test what I'll get, but it doesn't `echo` while provisioning, and doesn't create `extra_homestead_software_installed` file.

What I've missed here

Comment: Simplest explanation is that your conditional is failing.

Comment: if your provisioning is not running (you can see output during vagrant up) it means the condition does not work - just add a print of the condition to make sure how it gets evaluated

Comment: did `puts File.exist(afterScriptPath)`, correct? it prints `true`

Comment: could be some permission issue - is your file executable ?

Comment: yes, looks like this `-rwxrwxr-- 1 vlad vlad  883 Sep 29 21:53 after.sh`